# passing a null value to the database from a dropdownlist in the form of boolean in c#

Tags: c#, html, .net, database

In boolean you can pass 2 values, true or false, but m trying to pass a 3rd value (Null) from the dropdownlist , `approved= true(1), rejected=false(0), pending= (NULL)`, not able to pass the null value

```
<td>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged">
       <asp:ListItem Value="DBNull">Pending For Approval</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="1">Approve</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="0">Reject</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

else if (e.CommandName == "APPROVE")
            {

```
            bool? Status = null;
            string Request_ID = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1")).Text;
            string Employee_ID = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label2")).Text;
            string Certification_Name = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label3")).Text;
            string Issue_Date = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label4")).Text;
            string Valid_Till_Date = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label5")).Text;
            string Status = ((DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList3")).SelectedItem.Value;
            string Requested_On = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label6")).Text;
            string Approved_By = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label8")).Text;
            string Approved_On = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label9")).Text;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Request_For_External_Certification set Status='" + Status + "' where Request_ID=" + Request_ID,  con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            FillData();
```

error is showing ..failed to convert null value to bit
Tried to convert the valu also, but no luck

```
string status = Convert.ToBoolean(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a normal `bool` which can only have **true** or **false** value. You will need to use a [nullable](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiq0o3nzLTSAhVGEpQKHe4FCf4QFggYMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F2cf62fcy.aspx&usg=AFQjCNEaEz1nZT-JTTDKRFnXSCR8cb4OwA&bvm=bv.148441817,d.dGo&cad=rja) bool here. You can do it like this:

```
bool? status = null;
```

or

```
Nullable<bool> status = null;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes , but these values need to passed through in the html page, and not C#, in c#, the values will only be called to make a connection with the sqserver

Comment: Oh, didn't notice you updated your question description.

Comment: Can you show us the block of code where you're getting the error?

Comment: can you please check it now?

Comment: What happens when you change this  string Status = ((DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList3")).SelectedItem.Value; to this  bool? Status = ((DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList3")).SelectedItem.Value;

Comment: the selected value, which is approved or rejected is updated on the sqlserver

Comment: but the error comes when pending value is selected ,when the update button is clicked